# How I can see and display the use space and Total Space of a hard disk or USB, and have this space use in percentage with jProgressBar Java

Tags: java, swing

How I can see and display the use space and TotalSpace of a hard disk or usb, and have this space use in percentage with jProgressBar Java

Answer (score 1):

> How I can see and display the use space and TotalSpace of a hard disk or usb

- [`File#getFreeSpace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getFreeSpace--)
- [`File#getTotalSpace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getTotalSpace--)

or

- [`FileStore#getUnallocatedSpace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileStore.html#getUnallocatedSpace--)
- [`FileStore#getTotalSpace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileStore.html#getTotalSpace--)

See [The Path Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathClass.html) for more details

> and have this space use in percentage with jProgressBar Java

[How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html)

Comment: But I want to have all the usb or hard drive as a percentage`

Comment: @ConcourdChampion So? Read the links, understand how they work, try something, see what happens. If you have further issues, post what you've tried and what's not working - you'll get better responses when you put more effort into answering your own question - this is not an uncommon task and I'm sure there are plenty of examples of the basic concept around which you can find to build upon